# Employee turning 65 in future date

Tags: mysql

I have over 50K people in my system with their DOB under a tablename as Employee and column_name as Birth_date
i am trying to find the list of people who will be turnig 65 in the future date. can somebody please help me how would i write that query ?

Comment: Everyone younger than 65.

Comment: all i need is someone who hasnt turned 65 yet but will turn 65 in the future date.

Comment: Yes, that's "everyone younger than 65", unless you're predicting deaths of employees.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The point is: Your question does not show any evidence that you have already put some work into solving it yourself. What have you treid so far? Why did that not work? Narrow down your problem and do not expect people to do all the work for you.

Comment: i certainly did try multiple times, went thru various website to solve this issue before posting a question in this site but wasnt able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Use date arithmetic:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE Birth_date <= '2014-07-15' - INTERVAL 65 YEAR
```

Replace `2014-07-15` with whatever date you want to test.

Edit: Based on your comments, you want only people who are not yet 65, but will be as of some future date. In that case, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE Birth_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 65 YEAR AND '2025-01-01' - INTERVAL 65 YEAR
```

Again, replace the hard-coded date with whatever you want to check.

Comment: For performance, we'd prefer that the predicate references the bare column on one side. This would enable the optimizer to consider using an index range scan if an appropriate index is available. That is, we'd really like to see the "date arithmetic" on the "literal" side, so that will get performed just once, rather than having to perform the "date arithmetic" for every row in the table... e.g. **`birth_date <= '2014-07-15' - INTERVAL 65 YEAR`**.

Comment: @spencer7593 Good point; I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select * from Employee where Birth_date Between ('<future date'> - Interval 65 year ) AND  ('<future date'> + Interval 1 day - Interval 65 year )
```

Comment: OP is asking about checking an arbitrary future date, not people who are already 65, so `NOW()` won't work.

Comment: @EdCottrell noticed, see update

Comment: Nice use of `BETWEEN`.